# Dynamically add classes to host elements using @HostBinding in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-hostbinding

**Question:**

**Is it possible to use `@HostBinding` in such a way to add, remove, or toggle classes on a host element and not remove preexisting classes, in particular when the classes need to be dynamically toggled ?**

For example, this will add `light` class and be non-disruptive to the previous classes;however, `light` cannot be dynamic.

Imagine this rendered dom node:

```
<div [classToggler] class="someClasses1 someClasses2' ></div>
```

With this controller:

```
@HostBinding('class.light') isLight = theme === 'light';  // true
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select('classToggler').subscribe((className) => {
      this.theme = className || 'light'
  });

}
```

Where as this example controller, will add the light class dynamically but to my knowledge will remove other classes on host element.

```
@HostBinding('class') theme;

ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select('classToggler').subscribe((className) => {
      this.theme = className || 'light'
  });
}
```

In the end the second example will re-render the dom element to look like this:

```
<div [classToggler] class="light'></div>
```

**And therefore, remove the previous classes, which isn't desired. Any ideas on how to get the best of both worlds?**

Comment: Can you use a getter for `isLight` instead of assigning an expression? That might make it reactive in the same way as the second pattern. I'll see if I can mock up an example.

Comment: @RichardMatsen could you leave an answer the first answer isn't what I'm looking for? I want the ability to add (n) number of classes .light was just an example.

Comment: Will do. Still working on a Plunker (hate to post untested).

Answer (score 5):

Change this line

```
@HostBinding('class') theme;
```

to

```
@HostBinding('class') 
get themeClass(){
  return this.theme;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

What you need is [ngClass] like so :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'light':condition}" class="someClasses1 someClasses2" ></div>
```

When condition is true, "light" class will be added to someClasses1 someClasses2 and vice versa

You can even compose mulptiple classes with multiple situations like so :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1':condition1, 'class2':conditions2}" class="someClasses1 someClasses2" ></div>
```

you can add as many conditional classes as you need.

Comment: I think the OP is about a directive, so the solution has to be into the directive, not the html...

Comment: The purpose of a directive is to be easily reusable. For instance I've landed here trying to apply multiple classes with a single directive (the person using the directive does not have to know which exact classes has to be applied in order to get the expected behavior). I also guess OP was making a more complex directive, which, among other actions, needs to apply a class...

Comment: HostBinding means the OP needs the class on the host.